# How can I show modal , after button [action] is clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Well, I have modal-window where I have 2 buttons - pay and close.

Once pay is clicked, I need to show another modal-window

I have 2 modals as DIV's

```
<div class="modal unshowed popup-confirm-order fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="confirm_inprogress_done_popup_content" style="display: none;">
```

and here is Pay button

```
<button type="button" 
onclick="event.preventDefault();
$('#checkaccept-tid{MKT_ID} input[name=accept]').val(1);
$('#checkaccept-tid{MKT_ID}').submit();"
class="submit">Pay
</button>
```

and other DIV/Modal

```
<div class="modal popup-success-order fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="success_order_popup_content" style="display: none;">
```

Both divs/modals are working fine, tested using Demo Button , just changing ID's.

So, when user is working with 1 DIV (modal) there is a button, which he is clicking - Pay.

After this button is clicked, I need to show 2 DIV **success_order_popup_content**

really tired or brain totally do not work, cannot understand, how to display ..

was trying to call modal window when condition of other logic is true, but this is I guess bad idea.

Comment: `$('#confirm_inprogress_done_popup_content').show();` maybe??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.
I was calling

```
 <script>
  $('#success_order_popup_content').modal('show');
</script>
```

And it was not working, but it was NOT working because of my PHP Condition was written incorrect. Now all is good